# Expected value of absolute value of i.i.d random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics

If $X_{n}$ is a sequence of i.i.d random variables with mean $0$ and $E|X_{1}|<\infty$, can we conclude that $E|X_{j}|<\infty$, $\forall j$? If so, why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "with mean $0$" implies that $\mathbb E[|X_1|]<\infty$, so the latter statement is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If they are identically distributed, then  $$\forall j:\,E|X_{j}|= E|X_{1}|<\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood, $X_n$ is i.i.d then $E|X_j| = E|X_i| < \infty$, no?