# Expected value of absolute value of random variable to the n-th power

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have the following problem:

Let $k>0$ and $E[|X|^k]$. Asume $E[|X|^k]$ is finite and for each $j$ such that $0 < j < k $ then prove that $E[|X|^j] < \infty $.

I don't get how to go around this. I went with the integral definition but this got me nowhere. Then I searched for similar problems like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3877426/expected-value-of-absolute-value-of-i-i-d-random-variables) but they were not very helpful. I would appreciate some help or some references to books that could help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbf{E}[|X|^j]=\mathbf{E}[|X|^j\mathbf{1}\{|X|\leq1\}]+\mathbf{E}[|X|^j\mathbf{1}\{|X|>1\}]\leq1+\mathbf{E}[|X|^k\mathbf{1}\{|X|>1\}]\leq1+\mathbf{E}[|X|^k]<\infty$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matías Vera! I have just one doubt, what does the $\textbf{1} \{ |X| > 1 \} $ refers to? Is it like vector notation?

Comment: $\mathbf{1}\{X\in A\}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1&\text{if }X\in A\\0&\text{if }X\not\in A\end{array}\right.$